# Is wxReportWriter the right way to go for C++?

Tags: c++, reporting, codeblocks

I've lately been at cross-roads about choosing between Pascal (Lazarus) and C++ (Code::Blocks) for my projects. One of the key deciding factors has been the availability of a report designer tool.

I haven't tried either too well but this is my criteria in choosing one:

1. It must be easy to implement as a programmer
2. It must be portable (Windows/Linux). So I'm looking at write-once-compile-anywhere.
3. It must perform well.

Keeping this in mind, I have come across wxReportWriter but never really tried it.

My question: Is it the right way or the best way to go by using this reporting component for C++ or is there a better way of creating printable reports? Here's the link with sample code: http://www.daily.de/RepWrt/

Thanks!

Comment: Pascal is kinda dead.  I dont know if it is wise sticking to a language that is that old.

Comment: @Anycorn I think you got me wrong. Pascal is not the Turbo Pascal or the old DOS based thing. I'm referring to Lazarus/Free Pascal which is the only alternative to Delphi. But I must agree that looking at the work we have to do, it's nearly as much as we'd do for C++ with a framework like wxWidgets. But it is still easier as there are lesser issues to deal with when it comes to conversions and pointers. So Pascal is NOT dead. In fact, at the rate it's taken off, I won't be surprised if it becomes the next Python :)

Comment: If your target is to be cross platform compatible, then why not use Java?, if you know C++, Java would be easier and you can use Jasper Reports for reporting.

Comment: I closed the doors to Java about 3 years ago. I never liked the idea of 'borderless' programming. With Java I never enjoyed working with beans, swing, etc. Never knew where to draw the line. But with c++ and Pascal, we have a clear set of (limited) functions/libraries to work with. And on top of all, we haven't had the threats or vulnerabilities that Java has had :)